# Libgdx keeping the code neat

Tags: java, libgdx

I have written the following code. It all works ok. However, I have been told that it is written in the incorrect format. I am not exactly sure what the correct way of coding this would be. Any help would or direction be much appreciated.

```
package com.mygdx.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.mygdx.gameobjects.Egg;
import com.mygdx.gameobjects.Ground;
import com.mygdx.gameobjects.Hero;

public class GameWorld {

Hero hero = new Hero(); //This seems to the bit that causes some amusement.
Egg egg = new Egg(); //This seems to the bit that causes some amusement.
Ground ground = new Ground(); //This seems to the bit that causes some amusement.


public void update(float delta) {
    Gdx.app.log("GameWorld", "update");
    egg.update(delta);
    hero.update(delta);
    ground.update(delta);

}

public Hero getHero() {
    return hero;
}

public Egg getEgg() {
    return egg;
}

public Ground getGround() {
    return ground;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those commented variables are the *members* of your class. They have no *modifier*, which means that they are **visible only from inside the class or from classes in the same package**. This absolutely makes sense, if you would like to mock them while testing for example. In other cases, I would not recommend using them though, but make them private instead.

More about modifiers and class members: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

The code is basically ok, but a few changes should be made:

1. Formatting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in **Eclipse**, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in **Netbeans**).
2. Since you have getters, all fields should be private (otherwise they are visible in *com.mygdx.gameworld* package).
3. In my opinion it would be a little bit cleaner to move hero, egg, ground instantiation to the constructor.
4. Your fields/methods should not contain any comments unless there is some very complicated logic in it. Try to treat your code as a documentation.

I really recommend:
[Clean Code by Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)